# SQL Server function/stored procedure returns different data than same query outside function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query:

```
DECLARE @date date = '2017-09-13'
DECLARE @pos int = 111222
DECLARE @UserNo int = 122425
DECLARE @sameDist bit = 0
DECLARE @brandId int = NULL
DECLARE @sameArea bit = 0

SELECT 
    PosId, SUM(NetSales) as SumSales, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(NetSales) DESC) as RowID
FROM 
    dbo.t_Sales_Daily 
INNER JOIN  
    dbo.t_Pos ON dbo.t_Sales_Daily.PosId = dbo.t_Pos.Id
INNER JOIN 
    t_User ON dbo.t_Sales_Daily.RetailerNo = t_User.UserNo
WHERE 
    (CONVERT(DATE, SalesDate) = @date 
    AND (@brandId IS NULL OR BrandId = @brandId) 
    AND (@sameDist = 0 OR dbo.t_Pos.DistType = (SELECT TOP 1 DistType 
                                                FROM t_Pos WHERE Id = @pos)) 
    AND (@sameArea = 0 OR t_User.RegionName = (SELECT top 1 RegionName 
                                               FROM t_User WHERE UserNo = @userNo)))
GROUP BY 
    PosId
```

When I run this query with declared parameters I get about ~2000 rows, but when I insert this query into a stored procedure and run the stored procedure I get only about ~200 rows.

The query is exactly the same and I triple-checked that the query is the same and that the same parameters are passed through.

Here is how I execute the stored procedure:

```
exec dbo.GetPosRankDaily @userNo, @date, @pos, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

As I said the stored procedure does work but just returns less results (I used `set nocount on`), all results returned from the stored procedure are contained in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well I found the solution 1 second after posting the question...

Though in the stored proc i declared 2 bit paramaters with default 0 values, I passed null in the argument instead of 0 and it somehow yielded less results which is strange because it shouldn't have returned anything.

So basically running the sp as so solves the issue:

```
exec dbo.GetPosRankDaily @userNo,@date,@pos,NULL,0,0
```

Comment: Also be aware you are running `TOP 1` without an order by. That will also introduce random results

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The query only returns one result either way so its ok, I just did that as a precaution in case of human error when filling the db with data.

Comment: Good plan! I do the same thing myself.